# Onclick get part of edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need someone help me for focus text.
When I `Onclick` **EditText**, I need focus part of text:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you have already tried and explain where exactly you are facing the problem. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239524/android-ime-set-cursor-position-in-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
YourEditText.setSelection(2);
```